# MySQL insert based on datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, database

This is my first post ever, so I apologize if I unknowingly break any rules regarding post etiquette.

I am migrating db entries using C# and the Redmine API.  I need to pull the time entries in XML and insert into MySQL if and only if the time entries are newer than what exists currently in the database.

Right now I am prototyping this by simply rerouting the original MySQL db entries back to MySQL and into a new table.  Later I will using ERP software similar to SAP software.

I am not sure if the program logic needs to be primarily in the C# code, or in a MySQL statement.  Here is where I am stuck:

```
foreach (TimeEntry t in timeEntries.list)
{

   comm.CommandText =
     "INSERT INTO time_entries(time_entry_id,project_id,issue_id,user_id,activity_id,hours,comments,"
     + "spent_on,created_on,updated_on,customer_number)"
     + "VALUES(?time_entry_id,?project_id,?issue_id,?user_id,?activity_id,?hours,?comments,?spent_on,"
     + "?created_on,?updated_on,?customer_number)";
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?time_entry_id", t.id);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?project_id", t.project.Id);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?issue_id", t.issue.id);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?user_id", t.user.id);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?activity_id", t.activity.id);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?hours", t.hours);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comments", t.comments);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?spent_on", t.spent_on);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?created_on", t.created_on);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?updated_on", t.updated_on);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?customer_number", t.custom_fields.list[0].value);

     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     comm.Parameters.Clear();  
     continue; 
}
```

Of course, everything inserts just fine, and subsequent runs of the program will simply insert duplicate records.  When this is finished, the idea is that it will run as a daily cron job that will update MySQL with new time entries only.

As I mentioned, at a later point I will be sending the XML data directly to an ERP program similar to SAP software, but right now I want to make sure the MySQL to MySQL prototype works first.

I am a relatively new programmer, and a first time poster, so if there are flaws with my code logic or if my question is not specific enough then please let me know.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not pull the created_on/updated_on column from the db before the Insert and then just compare it to t.created_on/t.updated_on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just figured out a working solution.  Not sure if it is the best way to do it, but it works, so I am happy.

All I did was changed updated_on to be the primary key in MySQL, and then handled the exception that was thrown for duplicate entries:

```
try
                {
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException mySqlEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate entry found");
                }
```

I wanted to post the code in case it helps anyone else searching for an answer to this same issue.  As far as I am concerned, this problem is now solved.

Comment: Won't this make it so you have duplicate records, with just a different updated_on field?

Comment: @Scriven -- There appears to be absolutely no duplication of records with this method.  I set the updated_on field at the primary key in MySQL, and the MySqlException from the C# dll seems to check all entries against the datetime stamp.  Worked like a charm actually.

Comment: Yes my bad, I misread the question. This works fine for repeat data transfers of the same data. I thought you wanted to replace the record with a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DUAL

```
INSERT INTO time_entries (time_entry_id, project_id, issue_id, user_id,
                         activity_id, hours,comments, spent_on,
                         created_on, updated_on, customer_number) 
SELECT ?time_entry_id, ?project_id, ?issue_id, ?user_id, ?activity_id,
       ?hours, ?comments, ?spent_on, ?created_on, ?updated_on, 
       ?customer_number
FROM DUAL 
WHERE  '2015-11-20' NOT IN (SELECT YourTimeField from time_entries)
```

I tryed to write a clear example (hope you understood the logic)

Comment: The only problem I see is that the datetime will change continually based on new entries, so if I hard code something into the query, that only helps me for right now.  Ideally, this program would be set loose into the system so that it can automate record gathering for the purpose of invoice generation.  As I mentioned in the comment below, the MySqlException apparently checks for duplicate entries against the primary key that I defined in MySQL.  So far that is working exactly like I needed.